# Branch io to BigQuery using webhooks

Tags: google-bigquery, branch.io

Did anyone here try sending data from branch io to BigQuery using either webhooks or API? Can you outline the process?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. It's a general question on how to use a piece of software that has documentation as an employee of the company working on said product pointed out. No added value for the community. The OP simply didn't use all available resources for solving the problem and outsources their work onto somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster Here -

You can definitely send data from Branch through webhooks. On your Branch Dashboard you can go to Data Feeds > Webhooks and add click on `Add a New Webhook`.

Since you haven't defined much of your use case here, I'd suggest you to check our documenation on the same - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/webhooks